# How to add inline image by Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: json, outlook, microsoft-graph-api

### Background

When I use Outlook client to send a mail with inline image.

The image in html email looks like this, which has **cid**:

```
<img size="100" src="cid:3bb599fc-f3eb-465b-af83-aa6a495f563a" style="max-width:100%">
```

When I use

```
GET /me/messages/{messageId}/attachments
```

The **contentId** in the result returned matched the **cid** in html.

```
{
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
            "id": "aaa",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2017-11-30T09:32:09Z",
            "name": "image.png",
            "contentType": "image/png",
            "size": 100,
            "isInline": true,
            "contentId": "3bb599fc-f3eb-465b-af83-aa6a495f563a",
            "contentLocation": null,
            "contentBytes": "validBase64Bytes"
        }
    ]
}
```

### Using Microsoft Graph API

Now I am trying to use Microsoft Graph API to add inline image.

```
POST /me/messages/{messageId}/attachments
{
  "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
  "name": "1.jpg",
  "isInline": true,
  "contentBytes": "validBase64Bytes"
}
```

However, the `contentId` is null in the result returned.

```
{
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
    "id": "aaa",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2017-11-30T09:35:50Z",
    "name": "1.jpg",
    "contentType": "image/jpeg",
    "size": 100,
    "isInline": true,
    "contentId": null,
    "contentLocation": null,
    "contentBytes": "validBase64Bytes"
}
```

And if I set `contentId` manually in POST

```
POST /me/messages/{messageId}/attachments
{
  "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
  "name": "1.jpg",
  "isInline": true,
  "contentId": "myContentId",
  "contentBytes": "validBase64Bytes"
}
```

It will return the error

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Unable to read JSON request payload. Please ensure Content-Type header is set and payload is of valid JSON format.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "36e95f0a-ad75-46c6-b86c-d585a150b96d",
            "date": "2017-11-30T09:37:41"
        }
    }
}
```

So how to add inline image correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weird, I tried to run the exact same code again, it won't give me any error now.

```
POST /me/messages/{messageId}/attachments
{
  "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
  "name": "1.jpg",
  "isInline": true,
  "contentId": "myContentId",
  "contentBytes": "validBase64Bytes"
}
```

Not sure whether it is a temporary issue. I will inform Microsoft team to check the log.

If I am wrong for how to use the API, please definitely point out. Thanks.

*I will leave it here for future people to save some time to implement adding inline image.*